# Could be a good example of using a companion object (static) this way?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, companion-object

In my application there are some actions that users can take, including `redo` support.

Therefore, I felt the need to manage by objectizing `Action`, and I implemented it as follows.

**1. Implement** `RecoverableAction`

```
abstract class RecoverableAction {
    abstract fun getActionName(): String
    abstract fun run()
    abstract fun undoActionName(): String

    enum class List(val action: RecoverableAction) {
        CONTAINER_CREATE(ContainerActions.CREATE), 
        CONTAINER_COPY(ContainerActions.COPY), 
        CONTAINER_DELETE(ContainerActions.DELETE)
    }
}
```

**2. Implement** `Actions` for `Redo`

```
    class ContainerActions private constructor() {
        companion object {
            val CREATE = object : RecoverableAction {
                override fun run() {
                    //do create
                }
                override fun getActionName() = List.CONTAINER_CREATE.name
                override fun undoActionName() = List.CONTAINER_DELETE.name
            }

            val DELETE = object : RecoverableAction {
                override fun run() {
                    //do create
                }
                override fun getActionName() = List.CONTAINER_CREATE.name
                override fun undoActionName() = List.CONTAINER_DELETE.name
            }

            val COPY = object : RecoverableAction {
                override fun run() {
                    //do copy
                }
                override fun getActionName() = List.CONTAINER_CREATE.name
                override fun undoActionName() = List.CONTAINER_DELETE.name
            }
        }
    }
```

**3.** Do `Action` anywhere 2 way

```
    CotainerActions.CREATE.run()
    RecoverableAction.List.CONTAINER_COPY.action.run()
```

I do not like using `static` variables, but I do not want each `Action` to be instantiated each time it is executed from the user. I also implemented it as a `companion` so that I could run the corresponding `Action` directly from several different classes.

In addition, I need to implement the `redo` function by managing the actions executed by the user as a `stack`. The reason I implemented the Action supported by `RecoverableAction` as an `enum` is because I want to manage it in the `Action record stack` by `name` rather than `Action object`.

I have been thinking a lot about designing the structure to implement these requirements, but I think this can be a good structure. Could this be a "good way"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me,

> RecoverableAction.List.CONTAINER_COPY.action.run()

Seems messy.

---

Why not:

```
sealed class RecoverableActions {
    abstract val actionName: String

    abstract val undoActionName: String

    abstract fun run()

    object CreateAction : RecoverableActions() {
        override fun run() {
            //do create
        }
        override val actionName = CreateAction::class.java.simpleName
        override val undoActionName = DeleteAction::class.java.simpleName
    }

    object DeleteAction : RecoverableActions() {
        override fun run() {
            //do create
        }
        override val actionName = DeleteAction::class.java.simpleName
        override val undoActionName = CreateAction::class.java.simpleName
    }

    object CopyAction : RecoverableActions() {
        override fun run() {
            //do create
        }
        override val actionName = CopyAction::class.java.simpleName
        override val undoActionName = CopyAction::class.java.simpleName // ?
    }
}
```

And

```
RecoverableActions.CreateAction.run()
```

Comment: take care of `CopyAction::class.java.simpleName` if you are using obfuscation you could confront some bugs

Comment: That is true. Proguard rules are required for that sort of thing. Although if they are in the same package then it would still be ok. I'd probably just use a `Class<T>` there instead of the name.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice.
I saved only the name of the `Action` in the `Stack` that manages the Action, and when the user executes `redo`, I use the `enum` to get the Action object matched to that name and run {run()}. Is there a way to handle this if it is implemented as a `sealed class`? Also, is it an undesirable way to use a `companion` like I did?

Comment: Technically the issue with it is that you are re-implementing `enum`s (which internally are a class with static fields that contain the objects) -- meaning if you wanted to use `enum` instead of `sealed class`, then you could just define the abstract methods in the enum itself. That way you can ditch the `.List.`

Comment: I get a lot from you.
I did not think a sealed class would be applicable to this situation.
Also, I do not know about enum properly and I think I used it wrong.
I understand your explanation and I think I can apply a better structure.
Thank you.